# How to grant admin rights for the program with the console?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, console

I can't grant the admin rights with a usual way (through the properties window) since my user doesn't have admin rights. However I have a console with the admin rights running, can I use it to grant such rights for the specific .exe program?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing, I have no idea what I can do.